# Why the same code running time differs?

Tags: c++, c, benchmarking

Making a benchmark, i have tested and figured out interesting results.

```
//gcc -o code_in_c.exe code_in_c.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d, r;
    while (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d) != -1){
        r = a + b * c + d;
        printf("%d\n", r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and second file for cpp

```
//g++ -o code_in_cpp.exe code_in_cpp.cpp
#include <cstdio>
int main(){
    int a, b, c, d, r;
    while (scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d) != -1){
        r = a + b * c + d;
        printf("%d\n", r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it's the same code, except for first two lines.
the program need to read 4 integers from every line
perform arithmetic operations (multiply two integers from middle) and add from margins

```
1 2 3 4 -> 1 + (2 * 3) + 4 -> 1 + 6 + 4 -> 11
```

so, testing this with random numbers on a 150 000 lines
give me results for cpp

```
Running "code_in_cpp.exe", press ESC to terminate...
Program successfully terminated
  exit code:     0
  time consumed: 2.37 sec
  time passed:   4.34 sec
  peak memory:   2162688 bytes
```

and for c.

```
Running "code_in_c.exe", press ESC to terminate...
Program successfully terminated
  exit code:     0
  time consumed: 2.87 sec
  time passed:   4.57 sec
  peak memory:   2162688 bytes
```

So my question is what depends on running time?

(both was running on same machine)

Comment: I would assume the difference in running time is due to the difference between the `stdio.h` and `cstdio` header files (and functions implemented therein).

Comment: It would be interesting to see a plot of `#lines` versus `time` for C and C++.

Comment: Even though it's a trivial amount of code, and it's mostly I/O anyway, you should still compile with optimisations enabled (e.g. `-O3`) to get meaningful results.

Comment: FWIW, I got slightly better performance with g++ on Linux, using g++ 4.8.2. It is not significantly better but consistently better. Tested without using any optimization flags.

Comment: Repeat your test in alternation a few times and see if the results are consistent of if it was just a cache/timing effect.

Comment: How often have you tested this?

Comment: after testing some more, figured that cpp is faster but randoming.. 
c seems to be more stable.
testing results.
http://pastebin.com/GfF3z3nN

Comment: -1 for benchmarking without optimizations. That's never a good idea. Also, using lot's of I/O in a benchmark is also not that good. You should generate a random set of numbers first, then time the benchmark code and carefully take care of variables that may be optimized out.

Comment: @stefan the main idea of this benchmark was to test differences between i/o of c and cpp. please read the question.

Comment: @Daniel Well then don't call it "benchmark". The c++ compile probably does some optimizations. Or it's actually different versions of the underlying glibc. Who knows. It's highly platform and version dependent. It might also be your hard drive that caches the file or whatever. If you want to name it "benchmark", do it properly.

Answer (score 3):

this time is depend on very things like: OS context switch, memory management mechanism in OS , mechanism of runnig process (multi thread, multi core cpu , ...)

so, if we run one program 2 times, necessarily there is no reason that execution time of them become equal.

Comment: Do you know of any differences in the implementations of `scanf` and `printf` between the C and C++ versions?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen as i know they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the g++ links with the C++ standard libraries where the implementation of some functions may be slightly different from the C standard library implementation.

C++ standard library is backwards compatible with the C standard library but this doesn't mean there can't be performance improvements seen.

Answer (score 1):

In current OS's, program execution time is mostly a non-deterministic variable, meaning that even if you run the same C code twice, it could run in different time, depending on CPU usage and ocupation by the OS, memory management and current ocupation (does OS's uses cache in one of the executions?), etc... Also, as other users pointed out, it probably also depends on the implementation of standart libraries, since, although very similar, they are different languages.